# How to assign event handler programatically

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using DevExpress AspxGridView and I'm trying to assign OnCustomCallBack programatically in the Page_Load. but it didn't work. this is my code,

```
aspxGrid1.attributes.add("OnCustomCallback","MyServerSideFunctionName")
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
aspxGrid1.CustomCallback += new AspxGridViewCustomCallbackHandler(MyServerSideFunctionName);
```

(I have no DevExpress Controls so you have to adapt the delegates name.)

Or do you want to do it with Reflection?

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net, you would attach a handler in this fashion:

```
AddEventHandler aspxGrid1.CustomCallBack, addressof MyServerSideFunction
```